# How to parse next page by Beautiful Soup?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I use code as below to parse page with next page:

```
def parseNextThemeUrl(url):
  ret = []
  ret1 = []
  html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  html = BeautifulSoup(html, PARSER)
  html = html.find('a', class_='pager_next')
  if html:
    html = urljoin(url, html.get('href'))
    ret1 = parseNextThemeUrl(html)

    for r in ret1:
        ret.append(r)
  else:
    ret.append(url)
  return ret
```

But I got error as below, how can I parse next link if there is a link.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 162, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 456, in open
req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Comment: can you give us the weblink? we can't determine much without knowing the webpage.

Comment: `http://003.b2btoys.net/en/ProductList.aspx?Class1=12` `http://003.b2btoys.net/en/ProductList.aspx?PageIndex=2&Class1=13&Class2=0&type=&keyWord=`

Answer (score 0):

I got my own answer as below:

```
def parseNextThemeUrl(url):
  urls = []
  urls.append(url)
  html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
  new_page = soup.find('a', class_='pager_next')

  if new_page:
    new_url = urljoin(url, new_page.get('href'))
    urls1 = parseNextThemeUrl(new_url)

    for url1 in urls1:
        urls.append(url1)
  return urls
```